# Mybatis and PostgreSQL although the rows are deleted, multiple delete statements return 0

Tags: postgresql, mybatis

as the title says, when I execute multiple delete statements with a single Mybatis Delete annotation, it returns 0 rows. However, when I delete them separately, they both return the number of rows affected. Is there a way to return the number of rows affected from the last statement?

mybatis: 3.5.9
postgresql db: v14
org.posgresql driver: 42.3.3

```
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Delete;

import java.util.UUID;

public interface WorkspaceRepository {
    @Delete("delete from workspace_users where workspace_id = #{workspaceId}")
    int deleteWorkspace_1(UUID workspaceId); // returns 1

    @Delete("delete from workspaces where workspace_id = #{workspaceId}")
    int deleteWorkspace_2(UUID workspaceId); // returns 1

    @Delete("delete from workspace_users where workspace_id = #{workspaceId};" +
            "delete from workspaces where workspace_id = #{workspaceId}")
    int deleteWorkspace_1_and_2(UUID workspaceId); // returns 0
}
```

Comment: MyBatis just returns the value returned from the driver. If you put multiple statements in single `Statement#execute()` call, pgjdbc returns the number of rows affected by the first statement, IIRC. If you need the number of affected rows, you need to execute each DELETE separately.